# What is wrong with the syntax in this applescript?

Tags: applescript

I am beginning to work on a script that involves looking at all currently open windows. I am getting an error and I don't understand why.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theProcesses to application processes
    set allWindows to window of processes whose visible is true
    repeat with x from 1 to count allWindows
        set Pos to position of allWindows item x
    end repeat
end tell
```

If I understand correctly, allWindows is a list. And yet when I try to compile, I get the error "Syntax Error - Expected end of line but found class name." The error points to the line "set Pos to position of allWindows item x". What is wrong with my code?

Update: nevermind, got it!

Comment: Yes, AllWindows is a list, then try 'set Pos to position of item x of allWindows'

Comment: See my update above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your script, not only syntax error, but also incorrect understanding.

1) for the syntax, as mentioned before, you must address 'item x of allWindows' and not 'allWindows item x'

2) the variable allWindows contains a list, but each element is a list of a items.

Example {{window "imac27" of application process "Finder"}, {window "What is wrong with the syntax in this applescript? - Stack Overflow" of application process "Safari"}}

In each item, you have the list of windows for the process. Then, in order to address the window itself, you must address 'item y of item X of allWindows'

3)Item x of the list allWindows could be empty {}. The list contains the list of all windows of visible applications. For instance, Microsoft Excel could be running, but without document open. In this case, Excel is process visible, but list of its window is {}. Also, a process may have many windows open.

In the script bellow, corrections have been made, and it loops through all the windows of each process:

```
tell application "System Events"
set theProcesses to application processes
set allWindows to window of processes whose visible is true
repeat with x from 1 to count of allWindows -- loop through each process
    if item x of allWindows is not {} then -- only if process has visible windows
        repeat with Y from 1 to count of item x of allWindows -- loop through each window of the process
            set Pos to position of item Y of item x of allWindows
        end repeat
    end if
end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response.